Вывод чисел между min и max в порядке убывания
Имеется задание, которое мною выполнено, но следует сократить количество проверок до четырёх. Не могу понять как это сделать.
Условия:

найти max и min число среди чисел 10, 5, -1;
отобразить в строку в порядке убывания все числа в интервале (min, max);
для вывода чисел использовать цикл for;
не использовать методы max и min класса Math

Моё решение:
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             int number1 = 10;
             int number2 = 5;
             int number3 = -1;
             int max = 0;
             int min = 0;
             if ((number1 > number2) && (number2 > number3)) {
                 max = number1;
                 min = number3;
             } else if ((number3 > number2) && (number2 > number1)) {
                 max = number3;
                 min = number1;
             } else if ((number2 > number3) && (number3 > number1)) {
                 max = number2;
                 min = number1;
             } else if ((number1 > number3) && (number3 > number2)) {
                 max = number1;
                 min = number2;
             } else if ((number3 > number1) && (number1 > number2)) {
                max = number3;
                min = number2;
             } else if ((number2 > number1) && (number1 > number3)) {
               max = number2;
               min = number3;
             }
             for (max -= 1; max > min; max--) {
                 System.out.print(max + " ");
             }

        }
    }
  


Т.е. ваша задача отсортировать (с обменами) 3 числа за 4 сравнения. Это возможно, делайте простые, а не составные сравнения, вложенные друг в друга

Нужно написать свои max и min и жизнь существенно упростится.

Этот вопрос похож на: Как использовать переменную, добавленную в цикле, в основной части кода?; Сравнение возрастов. Нужно скорректировать код чтобы он работал с переменными min, max, middle. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос от

@NowhereMan, чем похож? о_О

@Qwertiy Вычисления минимума и максимума для трех чисел -- или нужно снова переписать этот код, чтобы соответствовал вопросу?

@NowhereMan, но ведь суть вопросов совершенно разная...

@Qwertiy, почему разная? Стоит задача найти минимум/максимум среди трёх чисел, основная проблема данного вопроса но следует сократить количество проверок до четырёх. Не могу понять как это сделать, приведён код с 6 проверками в худшем случае.  В дубликатах показаны разные варианты решения аналогичной задачи, где используется три проверки (оператора if).

Решение:

найти max и min число среди чисел 10, 5, -1 - нужно три проверки, чтобы найти min и max - сначала сравниваем (1) два числа и определяем min и max из них, потом третье число сравниваем (2) с min на предмет нового минимума, и напоследок третье число сравниваем (3) с max на предмет нового максимума;
отобразить в строку в порядке убывания все числа в интервале (min, max) и для вывода чисел использовать цикл for - значит, цикл будет такой for (; max >= min; max--);
не использовать методы max и min класса Math - не будем, обойдёмся сранениями из п. 1.


значит, нужно создать массив из трёх элементов подозреваю, что имеется в виду цикл for(i=min;i<=max...)

@MBo ну да, сделал то, что придумал себе себе сам. Исправлю.
